# I want to block all application in windows until user select option in combo box. Is it possible in WPF?

Tags: c#, windows, block

I am developing an application to capture production info. Application works fine. But there is a chance that user may ignore to login the application on system startup. Is there a way to compel the user to login to the application before startig their regular work?

Comment: Lookup "Windows Single-SignOn". I am pretty sure, no Client wants to login on every startup. Have the Application use the Windows User / AD User.

Comment: Maybe you should take a look for *top most window* and *full screen*.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this.
If you call this method on load of your main screen of your application, it will run on startup automaticaly.

```
    void InstallMeOnStartup()
    {
        try
        {
            Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey key = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true);
            Assembly curAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
            key.SetValue(curAssembly.GetName().Name, curAssembly.Location);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```